# How to remove N/A from the pivot slicer in excel?

Tags: excel

I want to delete or remove the N/A from the slicer. I dont want to show N/A on the particular chart?

Please anyone tell is it possible to remove N/A from the slicer? 
Provide me a solution both ways VBA/Excel?

[image: Pivot table slicer]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you

```
Click the PivotTable report.
The PivotTable Tools appear.

Excel 2016 and Excel 2013: On the Analyze tab, in the PivotTable group, click the arrow next to Options, and then click Options.

Excel 2010 and Excel 2007: On the Options tab, in the PivotTable group, click the arrow next to Options, and then click Options.

Click the Layout & Format tab, and then do one or more of the following:

Change error display     Select the For error values show check box under Format. In the box, type the value that you want to display instead of errors. To display errors as blank cells, delete any characters in the box.

Change empty cell display     Select the For empty cells show check box. In the box, type the value that you want to display in empty cells. To display blank cells, delete any characters in the box. To display zeros, clear the check box.
```

Link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hide-error-values-and-error-indicators-in-cells-d171b96e-8fb4-4863-a1ba-b64557474439